# Error message - size cannot exceed NA error

Tags: r

I am having an error code that is preventing me from running a code.

The error code is:

> Error in if (is.na(n) || n > 65536L) stop("size cannot be NA nor exceed 65536") :  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed**

Below is my code

```
dd.1 <- dist(data.1)
hc.ward = hclust(whs2018annexBdatscl, method="ward.D2")
w.tot <- numeric(20)
btw <- numeric(20)
for ( k in 2:20 ) {
clust <- cutree(hc.ward,k=k) 
w <- within(whs2018annexBdatscl,clust)
w.tot[k-1] <- sum(w)
btw[k-1] <- between(whs2018annexBdatscl,clust)
}
plot(2:20,w.tot[-1],pch=19,type="b",xlab="K")
plot(2:20,btw[-1],pch=19,type="b")
plot(2:20,(btw[-1]/(2:20))/(w.tot[-1]/(nrow(data.1)-2:20)),pch=19,type="b")
```

Here is `str(whs2018annexBdatscl)`:

```r
 num [1:194, 1:36] -0.0254 -0.2468 0.0161 -0.2667 -0.0662 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:194] "Afghanistan" "Albania" "Algeria" "Andorra" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:36] "TotalPopulation" "LifeExpectancyM" "LifeExpectancyF" "LifeExpectancyB" ...
 - attr(*, "scaled:center")= Named num [1:36] 38300.3 69.5 74.3 71.9 63.3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:36] "TotalPopulation" "LifeExpectancyM" "LifeExpectancyF" "LifeExpectancyB" ...
 - attr(*, "scaled:scale")= Named num [1:36] 1.43e+05 7.15 7.81 7.42 6.75 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:36] "TotalPopulation" "LifeExpectancyM" "LifeExpectancyF" "LifeExpectancyB" ...
```

Comment: (1) Can you please any eliminate any extraneous code, i.e. any code *after* the error occurs? I suspect you're having problems in the second line, with the `hclust()` call, as searching the R code base for that error message leads [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d22ee2fc0dc8142b23eed9f46edf76ea9d3ca69a/src/library/stats/R/hclust.R#L67).

Comment: (2) There are some odd things about your code. You define `dd.1` in the first line, but don't use it thereafter. What is `whs2018annexBdatscl`? Can you at the very least show us `str(whs2018annexBdatscl)` ? (I suspect that you are trying to do clustering on a distance matrix that is too large...)

Comment: (3) most of the other posts I found including this error message (either on StackOverflow or elsewhere) have to do with passing the wrong kind of object to `hclust()`.

Comment: @BenBolker - I added the data structure below the question. I removed dd.1, but I still got the same error. whs2018annexBdatscl is the scaled version of my data. Thank you for the help.

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49721769/r-hierarchical-clustering-issue-with-input-matrix (and several others). You can't pass a raw data matrix to `hclust()`, you need to pass a dissimilarity/distance matrix.  Try `hclust(dd.1)`

Comment: After passing hclust(dd.1). I got: Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: And hclust(dd.1) resulted inError in hclust(dd.1, method = "ward.D2") : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 10)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do step-by-step remote debugging. (1) Have you googled "hclust NA NaN Inf"? (2) have you checked for non-finite values in your original data and/or your distance matrix? (3) Can we have a [mcve] ... ???